# How do I use categorical attributes as input to a clustering algorithm?

Tags: python, algorithm, machine-learning

I am working on a task in which I have to apply machine learning to cluster the users according to their behavior and background. While some of the attributes I have are numerical, most of them are categorical.

Most of the machine learning algorithms I read about use only numerical attributes to process data.

Does there exist any clustering algorithm which takes categorical attributes as input?

If not, how to convert categorical attributes into numerical attributes?

Comment: [LightGBM from Microsoft](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Python-intro.html#specific-feature-names-and-categorical-features) supports categorical features as it is. Or you convert it to numerical by techniques such as one-hot encoding, binarizing etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert categorical features to indicator variables(also known as dummy variable). You can also use [one hot encoder](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html).

Example:
Let's say there is one TYPE feature in your data. There are three categories in it.

```
data = pd.DataFrame(['A','B','C'],columns=['TYPE'])

data
Out[24]: 
  TYPE
0    A
1    B
2    C

#Use get_dummies on pandas dataframe. 

new_data = pd.get_dummies(data,columns=['TYPE'],prefix='TYPE_')

new_data
Out[26]: 
   TYPE__A  TYPE__B  TYPE__C
0      1.0      0.0      0.0
1      0.0      1.0      0.0
2      0.0      0.0      1.0
```